# Authenticating Adobe .pdf electronic signatures

Tags: authentication, digital-signature

Having created a certificate for electronic signing within Adobe Acrobat DC, can I authenticate documents signed using it by issuing a signed paper statement to recipients stating that it would be authentic if the properties of the e-signature show the public key to be 'xxxxx'?

In other words, could another party create an Adobe digital signature whose public key shows up as identical in the properties/details?

Comment: Public keys are public, so they are known. I don't know if it is possible to forge the data in an Adobe e-signature to include a random key, though. But you are missing the point of a signature. The point is not that the public key is the same, but that the signature is valid. Don't circumvent the signature by pointing people to what is public data in the document. That's like saying, "if my name is at the bottom of the letter, then you know it's from me."

Comment: I may not have explained myself. The idea is that someone receiving .pdf documents from me with my digital signature can right-click the signature in Adobe Acrobat to examine it's properties, including it's public key. I'd like them to be able to know for sure that I'm the one who signed it by comparing the public key generated by the Adobe programme with the written public key on the hard copy that I've previously provided them with.

Comment: Right, that's exactly what I thought you meant.

Comment: OK, so not trying to circumvent electronic signatures but to avoid the need for third party authentication organisations e.g. I may give or send you by post a signed legally valid statement saying Adobe files with an electronic signature whose public key is 'xxx' have been signed authentically by me with my private key. All subsequent .pdf communications or documents between us can then potentially be authenticated. It only works, however, if no-one else can generate the same public key in an Adobe electronic signature.